# How to restore ubuntu backup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, acronis-trueimage

I try to find a solution for my problem. I spent 3 days working, searching on this.
My story:
In  2010, i had installed  ubuntu and windows 7. After half a year i made a backup with Acronis Boot CD, just from the ubuntu. This was installed to a separate partition to that i can access from the windows 7.

Now i try to install the tib file to a Virtual Machine(VMWARE).

Solution 1: I set the cd drive to Acronis Boot CD. When the booting was finished i start to recover my .tib file. This solution does not work. When i try to boot ubuntu or windows 7, the  i got an error message to fix my partition:

"Failed to start ....", something boot errors, i deleted this vm yesterday.

Solution 2: I install Acronis Bakcup & Recovery 11 and revoer the backup to a new virtual machine. I choose every disk C 100 MB Disk1/System reserved (C:) and NTFS(F:) Size:55.60GB Dis 1/NTFS.

```
I got this error message: 
Press any key to boot from CD or DVD........
BOOTMGR is missing
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

With the Acronis BackUp and Recovery center 11, i can open the tib file.
structure of the F drive is the same as 2 year ago.
Inside the tib file:

```
root folder - C: F: drives
F: $RECYCLE.BIN hidden
   System Volume information hidden
   ubuntu
     disks
       root.dis
       swap.disk
       boot
        empty
     install
       .fuse_hidden000000000000000004000000000001
     winboot
       wubildr
       ....
     ubuntu.ico
     uninstall-wubi.exe
```

How can i restore my ubuntu? It's contain very important files and a ruby website configuration.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the files you could try booting ubuntu from a virtual CD in your virtual 
machine and see if you can get at the files that way

My guess is that Acronis constructed a MBR sector that does not work with your partition. You 
could try installing a boot manager.

Another possibility is that your old boot manager can't find it's data, possibly because the partitions have been renumbered. IF you have a boot CD (image) for it, perhaps it can repair itself.